# MySQL query with multiple union and group by

Tags: mysql, performance, query-optimization

My database schema is something like this:

desc SUB:

```
+-------+-------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| Field | Type        | Null | Key | Default | Extra          |
+-------+-------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| id    | int(11)     | NO   | PRI | NULL    | auto_increment |
| name  | varchar(30) | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
+-------+-------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
```

desc Cs:

```
+--------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| Field        | Type         | Null | Key | Default | Extra          |
+--------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| id           | int(11)      | NO   | PRI | NULL    | auto_increment |
| other_detail | varchar(255) | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| created_at   | datetime     | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| sub_id       | int(11)      | NO   | MUL | NULL    |                |
+--------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
```

desc Ap:

```
+--------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| Field        | Type         | Null | Key | Default | Extra          |
+--------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| id           | int(11)      | NO   | PRI | NULL    | auto_increment |
| other_detail | varchar(255) | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| created_at   | datetime     | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| sub_id       | int(11)      | NO   | MUL | NULL    |                |
+--------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
```

desc U:

```
+------------+-------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| Field      | Type        | Null | Key | Default | Extra |
+------------+-------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| id         | int(11)     | NO   | PRI | NULL    |       |
| type       | varchar(30) | NO   |     | NULL    |       |
| created_at | datetime    | NO   |     | NULL    |       |
| sub_id     | int(11)     | NO   | MUL | NULL    |       |
+------------+-------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
```

desc TR:

```
+--------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| Field        | Type         | Null | Key | Default | Extra          |
+--------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| id           | int(11)      | NO   | PRI | NULL    | auto_increment |
| other_detail | varchar(255) | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| created_at   | datetime     | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| sub_id       | int(11)      | NO   | MUL | NULL    |                |
+--------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
```

desc PR:

```
+--------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| Field        | Type         | Null | Key | Default | Extra          |
+--------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| id           | int(11)      | NO   | PRI | NULL    | auto_increment |
| other_detail | varchar(255) | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| created_at   | datetime     | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| sub_id       | int(11)      | NO   | MUL | NULL    |                |
+--------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
```

desc ID:

```
+--------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| Field        | Type         | Null | Key | Default | Extra          |
+--------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| id           | int(11)      | NO   | PRI | NULL    | auto_increment |
| other_detail | varchar(255) | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| created_at   | datetime     | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| cs_id        | int(11)      | NO   | MUL | NULL    |                |
+--------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
```

My req is to find all those `sub_id` whose total count in combined table `ID` (fetched from foreign key `CS_id` and Cs has `sub_id`), `PR` (`sub_id`), `TR` (`sub_id`), `AP` (`sub_id`) is less than N  and whose `created_at` is within one month from now and `u.type = 'fixed_value'`.

My approach is to find the count in each of the table group by `sub_id` and the group at backend and find the count.

```sql
SELECT count(*) as action_count, SUB.id  FROM Ap INNER JOIN  SUB ON Ap.sub_id = SUB.id INNER JOIN U  ON U.sub_id = SUB.id WHERE (Ap.created_at >= '2016-07-14') AND (Ap.created_at <= '2016-08-15') AND (U.type = "Customer") AND  (U.created_at <= '2016-07-14') GROUP BY SUB.id HAVING action_count > 0

SELECT count(*) as action_count, SUB.id  FROM PR INNER JOIN  SUB ON PR.sub_id = SUB.id INNER JOIN U  ON U.sub_id = SUB.id WHERE (PR.created_at >= '2016-07-14') AND (PR.created_at <= '2016-08-15') AND (U.type = "Customer") AND  (U.created_at <= '2016-07-14') GROUP BY SUB.id HAVING action_count > 0

SELECT count(*) as action_count, SUB.id  FROM TR INNER JOIN  SUB ON TR.sub_id = SUB.id INNER JOIN U  ON U.sub_id = SUB.id WHERE (TR.created_at >= '2016-07-14') AND (TR.created_at <= '2016-08-15') AND (U.type = "Customer") AND  (U.created_at <= '2016-07-14') GROUP BY SUB.id HAVING action_count > 0

SELECT count(*) as action_count, SUB.id  FROM ID INNER JOIN Cs on ID.cs_id = Cs.id inner join SUB ON Cs.sub_id = SUB.id INNER JOIN U  ON U.sub_id = SUB.id WHERE (ID.created_at >= '2016-07-14') AND (ID.created_at <= '2016-08-15') AND (U.type = "Customer") AND  (U.created_at <= '2016-07-14') GROUP BY SUB.id HAVING action_count > 0
```

Then the result obtained is grouped again by `SUB.id` at backend and the sum of `action_count` is calculated and all those `SUB.id` removed whose count < N.

How can I optimize this? It is known to us that 80% of SUB_id falls in category of `action_count > N`, so obtaining all then filtering at backend is very bad idea.

I cannot remove all `sub_id` < N in individual queries because it may be possible that in one query it has count < N, other > N, and rest 0. So, it will be considered to have count < N which is wrong.

Will Union all then group by and filter by count at DB be helpful in this case?

```sql
Select sum(action_count) as count , sub_id from (SELECT count(*) as action_count, SUB.id as sub_id FROM Ap INNER JOIN  SUB ON Ap.sub_id = SUB.id INNER JOIN U  ON U.sub_id = SUB.id WHERE (Ap.created_at >= '2016-07-14') AND (Ap.created_at <= '2016-08-15') AND (U.type = "Customer") AND  (U.created_at <= '2016-07-14') GROUP BY SUB.id HAVING action_count > 0
union all 
SELECT count(*) as action_count, SUB.id  as sub_id  FROM PR INNER JOIN  SUB ON PR.sub_id = SUB.id INNER JOIN U  ON U.sub_id = SUB.id WHERE (PR.created_at >= '2016-07-14') AND (PR.created_at <= '2016-08-15') AND (U.type = "Customer") AND  (U.created_at <= '2016-07-14') GROUP BY SUB.id HAVING action_count > 0
union all 
SELECT count(*) as action_count, SUB.id  as sub_id  FROM TR INNER JOIN  SUB ON TR.sub_id = SUB.id INNER JOIN U  ON U.sub_id = SUB.id WHERE (TR.created_at >= '2016-07-14') AND (TR.created_at <= '2016-08-15') AND (U.type = "Customer") AND  (U.created_at <= '2016-07-14') GROUP BY SUB.id HAVING action_count > 0
union all 
SELECT count(*) as action_count, SUB.id  as sub_id  FROM ID INNER JOIN Cs on ID.cs_id = Cs.id inner join SUB ON Cs.sub_id = SUB.id INNER JOIN U  ON U.sub_id = SUB.id WHERE (ID.created_at >= '2016-07-14') AND (ID.created_at <= '2016-08-15') AND (U.type = "Customer") AND  (U.created_at <= '2016-07-14') GROUP BY SUB.id HAVING action_count > 0) A group by sub_id having count < 30
```

But, this is also doing filter at last stage. How can I further optimise this?

**Note**: I have already asked this question at https://codereview.stackexchange.com/, but as I could not get solution, so reposting here too. Sorry for this.

Answer (score 1):

First, see if

```
SELECT  count(*) as action_count, SUB.id
    FROM  Ap
    INNER JOIN  SUB  ON Ap.sub_id = SUB.id
    INNER JOIN  U  ON U.sub_id = SUB.id
    WHERE  (Ap.created_at >= '2016-07-14')
      AND  (Ap.created_at <= '2016-08-15')
      AND  (U.type = "Customer")
      AND  (U.created_at <= '2016-07-14')
    GROUP BY  SUB.id
    HAVING  action_count > 0
```

can be written this way and get the same answer:

```
SELECT  count(*) as action_count, SUB.id
    FROM  SUB
    WHERE  EXISTS(
        SELECT  *
            FROM  Ap
            WHERE  sub_id = SUB.id
              AND  created_at >= '2016-07-14'
              AND  created_at <= '2016-08-15' 
                 )
      AND  EXISTS(
        SELECT  *
            FROM  U
            WHERE  sub_id = SUB.id
              AND  type = "Customer"
              AND  created_at <= '2016-07-14' 
                 )
```

For speed, add these indexes:

```
U: INDEX(sub_id, type, created_at)
AP: INDEX(sub_id, created_at)
```

Note that the `GROUP BY` is eliminated, giving some speed.  And the `HAVING` is eliminated, thereby leading to a smaller result set.

Now build the `UNION ALL` from queries like that.

Comment: Is it a bad coding practice if instead of union, I fire separate queries and do group by for final count  at code level?

Comment: _Usually_ it is both faster and less code and clearer to do the `UNION` in SQL rather than simulating it in client code.

Comment: _Usually_ it is bad practice to have multiple tables (AP,TR,PR,ID) with the _same_ set of columns.  If they can be combined, the `UNION` goes away?

Comment: Actually all these are different entities, say Actions, which are very different, just has a common key. Based on  that common key, I will need to find count of actions.